# Weston VNC together with QT

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto, wayland, weston

I have custom yocto image running on Raspberry pi CM4 with wayland and I am running my QT app on top of the weston13 which is displaying my app on DSI screen.

I would love to be able to VNC directly into my app for easy debugging, but I am not sure how to do that.

On screen I want to display only my app and nothing else, so no desktop environment, I am using kiosk shell (fullscreen doesnt work for some reason). I am able to connect through vnc but my screen is just black.

I tested the desktop-shell which works fine, my app displays but not fullscreen and i am able to connect but even that creates new "session" instead of displaying what is currently on screen.

I couldnt really find any info on this topic so I feel like I am missing something.
Does weston currently support only desktop-shell for vnc?

Sorry